# AWS - How to find all AWS products that interact with a MySQL DB?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services

Recently I was given a responsibility on some product running at AWS. This product includes several web-services running on EC2 instances and several databases (MySQL, DynamoDB etc').

Since there is barely any documentation, I'm still trying to wrap my head around the architecture of the data flow. Do I have a way, given a known MySQL DB - for example, to map out its' interactions with other AWS resources? For instance: some EC2 tries to write / read data from the database; A lambda is pushing data from that database to S3, and so on.

I've tried looking at cloudtrail logs and found them pretty insufficient. Is there another way?

I would prefer if this could be done through awscli obviously, but a GUI solution could also work if it exists.

Comment: Was the solution created from a CloudFormation template by chance? If so, you could open that up in the designer and it might give you a more visual look at the infrastructure.

Comment: Sadly it wasn't... Thanks anyway!

Comment: If the resources are properly secured (a big if) you could look at the security policy for each to see what accounts have access.  If a VPC and/or firewalled you could see what other IPs have been given access.  If an account or service can't connect or authenticate, it isn't using it.  If they are wide open and/or you use one has-all-rights account everywhere, that's something to fix.

Comment: That's a good idea! I will try to do that.

Comment: You can always also block the incoming connection and see where the system breaks.